# Writing to file from stdout

Tags: c, file, newline, msvcrt

I am creating an EXE, which is used with stdin and stdout streams.

The output of my executable is writing some compressed data to the stdout stream.

```
  int fd = fileno(stdout);
  _setmode(fd, O_BINARY);
  n = write(fd, buffer, nbytes);
```

But when I am re-directing to those data which are written to stdout stream, to a file,(using  **my_exe get_data > File.txt** ), the data length in the file will be mismatching with original data.If I have a 100 character data, then in the file, I am seeing 106 chars data. I think some newline or carriage return is getting added to the file. I have set the stdout to binary stream. but while re-directing to file,  the same is happening. Is there any way to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you examine the resulting file in a hex editor?

Comment: Can you show how `buffer` and `nbytes` are defined and assigned?

Comment: Are you expecting the compressed output to be *smaller* than the input? it won't always be on small data samples.

Comment: Do you have an example of a good file you can compare your results against?

Comment: yes, I compared the resulting file. I am seeing some extra' 0d ' in the output file.

Comment: What happens when you redirect to `File.dat` instead of `File.txt`?

Comment: Still seeing the same behaviour even after using .dat

Comment: Can you make `fd` a parameter and try writing directly to a file?

Comment: How are you looking at the file?

Comment: @Jason : Sorry I didn't get you. Could you please say more detailed?

Comment: @ stark : I used notepad++ editor to see the contents and file size. Also using hex editor for comparison.

Comment: Can you modify your source to use `fd` as a parameter instead of always using `stdout` and include the results in your question?

Comment: I notice you are using `_setmode` a MS Visual C++ function replacing `setmode` which is deprecated. Yet you are using the deprecated `fileno` and `write` instead of `_fileno` and `_write`. Does this affect things?

Comment: @WeatherVane : Yes!!!! It works. That was the actual issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you saying that you get a different result using `write` than `_write`? That sounds unlikely. In the library, the symbol for `write` is just an alias symbol for `_write`. There is literally no difference between them. The same is true for `fileno` and `_fileno`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis in that case, I must have caused OP to do something that got round some "finger trouble".

Comment: @JamesMcNellis thank you for that. This is why askers should post MCVE. In my recent simple test of the code posted, everything works perfectly well. The `\n` in the buffer is expanded, or not, depending on the presence of `_setmode(fd, O_BINARY);`.

Comment: This seemed odd to me as well, but I generally don't use WinAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `_setmode` a MS Visual C++ function replacing `setmode` which is deprecated. Yet you are using the deprecated `fileno` and `write`.

Please use `_fileno` and `_write`.

Comment: With the exception of the deprecation warning, there is no difference between calling `write` and calling `_write`.  In the library, the `write` symbol is just an alias for `_write`. The same is the case for `fileno` and `_fileno`.

Comment: I expect that it didn't.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis why would OP say it did, when it didn't? I posted this as an answer in response to comments.